# Bootstrap Grid push priority

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I using Bootstrap to build a website. In the header I want the website title in the top left hand side of the screen, the links to other pages next to it on the right, and the tagline underneath the website title on the left also. This is all fine and working, however as expected, when the screen size in made smaller into mobile/tablet, the menu goes underneath the title and the tagline goes underneath the menu.

How can I get the tagline to go underneath the website title when the grid changes? Is it the grid tags that I am using?

```
<div class="header">    
   <div class="fluid-container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class=".col-md-12">
               <h1 class="title">WEBSITE TITLE</h1>
                    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-link"><a href="/home/">Home</a></button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-link"><a href="/about/">About</a></button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-link"><a href="/services/">Services</a></button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-link"><a href="/gallery/">Gallery</a></button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-link"><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></button>
                    </div>                     
            </div>        
        </div>
        <div class=".col-md-12">
            <p class="tagline">Website Tagline</p>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Many thankings

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems.

- Change css class "fluid-container" to "container".  This will allow you to change widths of each `<div>`
- Class name of ".col-md-12" is not valid in the HTML.  Correct usage would "col-md-12".
- If you want the same width for all screen widths, then you should use class "col-xs-12" instead of 'col-md-12'.  The latter class is only valid with the screen is wider than 970px.
- The tagline needs to be surrounded with a `<div class='row'></div>` so that the contents would be on the same line.

`<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
               <h1 class="title">WEBSITE TITLE</h1>
                <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                    ...
                    ...
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
              <p class="tagline">Website Tagline</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>`

I have a working sample at - http://jsbin.com/cegaya/1/